# Language translation from one country to other in salesforce

Tags: translation

i got a scenario: if at all i want to use this kind of scenario, what should i do.suppose: if my client have business in USA and UK, now, while client operating site from USA he should read every thing in English, if the client is opening site from UK (Germany) he should be able to read every thing in German language. How should i configure and where can control

Comment: try formulating your question a bit better and add some tags to your post like translation. If I understand it correctly, you just need user A to see Salesforce in English and user B seeing Salesforce in German? If that is the case, each user can choose for himself the language in which he wants to see Salesforce through his personal settings in Salesforce. (click on the username, then "My Settings") Then offcourse, you need to translate your custom fields, objects etc. Have a look at this: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Do you mean the application, or the data created by your client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the factor that decides the client is working from US or UK?

We could make use of the translational workbench but it is important to understand how you decide the location of the client.